# How to delete some elements from UITableViewController with CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, uikit

So i can add some city from API and when i try to delete some city from UITableViewController then all cities are deleted. Can someone help me please where i made mistake. I gave an example of the code below

```
//this is my delete func from CoreData
 func deleteCity() {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Cities> = Cities.fetchRequest()

        if let cities = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
            for city in cities {
                context.delete(city)
            }
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    //this is how i create cities array 
    func fetch() -> [Weather] {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Cities> = Cities.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            let cities = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return cities.map({Weather(name: $0.cityName ?? "", temp: $0.cityTemp)})
        } catch  {
            return []
        }
    }

    //and this how i try to delete city from UITableViewController
 
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let actionDel = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { _, _, completionHandler in
            self.cityTemps.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.coreDataManaer.deleteCity()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        let actions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [actionDel])
        return actions
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `deleteCity()` function actually deletes all cities. Here's why:

First your fetch request fetches **all** cities, since there's no predicate:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Cities> = Cities.fetchRequest()
```

Then your loop goes through the results of the fetch and deletes every city it finds-- which is all of them.

```
if let cities = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
    for city in cities {
        context.delete(city)
    }
}
```

It sounds like you want to delete only the city that the person swipes on, which is the city at `indexPath` in the last function above. You could change your fetch request, but you probably don't need to do that. In your data source methods (for example your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` function) you already have a list of the cities you're showing, probably in an array. To delete a single city then, you'd do something like

1. Get the correct city from that array
2. Delete that city from the managed object context.